# Select distribution samples Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to know if there are a method in binary class to select randomly a subset of samples in order to obtain a positive distribution percentage X.

Suppose I have 100 samples, 70 negative and 30 positives. Which leads 30% distribution. Then apply a method to remove randomly some samples to obtain 50% distribution which mean 30 negative and 30 positive with 60 samples.

Is there anything?

Comment: Maybe look into this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold.html

Comment: Yes this validation preserve class when splitting train/test set but it doesn't remove samples.

Comment: It gives you indexes which you can use to select the samples from your data. You would be 'repurposing' the function for what you're trying to do, not for CV

Comment: There is no ready-made function, but it is very simple to just get the number of samples in the smaller class and sample as many points from the larger class. You could also use class_weights or sample_weights btw.

Comment: I decided to make a function which takes the samples and remove one samples at a time (depends if the chosen distribution is more than the original then I remove negatives samples and in the other way I remove positives) until the desired distribution is met. The selection is doing with Random.randint which perform uniformly random choices. I think it should work.

Comment: It would probably be much faster if you separated the two classes, and then picked from the larger one using np.random.choice

Comment: That is what I was searching!. Thanks!